# Submit form using text link using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I'm currently using:

```
$j('#ContinueButton').click( function() {       
$j("#valuation").validate({   
    ignore: ":hidden:not(select)",
    errorElement: "div",
    rules: {},
    messages: {},
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}  

}).form();
});
```

To validate a form using jquery validate. The continue button (instead of a standard submit button for reasons that don't need explaining, that's just how it is...) is pressed, the form validates and throws up errors when needed, but if there are no errors the form doesn't submit. I've tried using:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    form.submit();
}
```

On the end, but that doesn't send the form either.

Have tried a few things and nothing seems to submit the form when it's correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have your validator definition inside a click function what you really want is:

```
$j('#ContinueButton').click( function(event) {       
    event.preventDefault();
    $j("#valuation").submit();
});

$j("#valuation").validate({   
    ignore: ":hidden:not(select)",
    errorElement: "div",
    rules: {},
    messages: {},
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {} ,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

This way your continue button will submit the form, and jQuery validator will handle the form, 2 separate things.